# Cascading MVC controllers with CatchAll Routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC app which has its routes defined with the final route being a catch all route to a "PageController" for a database driven collection of pages. What I want to achieve is to be able to plugin to the app a second controller to the catch all route which the first controller passes on to if it does not find the url recieved in the database.

Effectively I want to queue up controllers with catch all actions:

```
public ActionResult PageCatchall(string url)
{
    var page = repository.Get<Page>(string url);
    if (page != null)
    {
        // Handle the request
       return View(page)
    }
    // Otherwise pass to a new controller

   ????
}
```

Anyone have any good ideas as to how to solve this? I have tried RedirectToAction but that requires that the next controller has a different route to the action. I have tried ActionInvoker but this failed to work the way I did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I would avoid complex routing like this one, I guess best thing to do is to use [custom route constraint](https://weblogs.asp.net/stephenwalther/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints) that uses cached list of `pages` to match correct route (have done that with success).

I'll leave exact implementation for You as an exercise. ;o)